# How do I limit PHP apps to their own directories and their own php.ini?

Tags: php, apache, include, subdomain, server-side-includes

I am running multiple PHP apps on my Mac, running OS X 10.5.6, Apache 2, PHP 5.  I have subdomains setup for each project, a host file entries for each subdomain, and Virtual Directory blocks in the Apache config.  So

project1.localhost goes to /Library/WebServer/Documents/Project1
project2.localhost goes to /Library/WebServer/Documents/Project2
etc...

However, this method doesn't really "isolate" the web apps.  For example, if I include a script like so:

```
<?php
include("/includes/include.php");
?>
```

It references the script from the base directory of my computer.  So it accesses
C:/includes/include.php

Is there a way for me to make it reference
C:/Library/WebServer/Documents/Project2/includes/include.php

Basically, make it so that its not aware of anything outside of its own directory.  Also, is there a way to use php.ini's on a per subdomain basis as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's possible to set a php.ini per virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    PHPINIDir /full/path/to/php/ini/

</VirtualHost>
```

this way you can customize open_basedir and others

Comment: What do you mean by "this way you can customize open_basedir and others".  Is open_basedir an INI setting?

Comment: yes, and thats why using 'php_admin_value open_basedir "/path"' also works

Answer (score 5):

You can limit a scripts ability to see anything above a specific folder tree by adding the [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.open-basedir) directive a folder block in the httpd.conf file.  It should look like:

> <DIRECTORY /full/path/to/folder/containing/script/>
>
> php_admin_value open_basedir "/full/path/to/top/folder/of/desired/tree/"
>
> </DIRECTORY>

One thing - if you don't end the path with a / then it's a wildcard match.  In other words,  "/var/etc/my" will match "/var/etc/myFolder" as well as "/var/etc/myMothersFolder", while "/var/etc/my/" will only match that exact folder name.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to trying this yet, but are there any caveats with using this method?

Comment: Caveats? Like what? With the open_basedir directive or with putting the directive in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: I haven't found any gotchas that aren't explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding application isolation ~ is this in regards to *securing* PHP scripts so they cannot access others? Please elaborate -

Regarding php.ini - I am not aware of any way to use a specific php.ini per directory, but you could certainly create a php include page with a bunch of ini_set() lines, perhaps something like this ..

```
<?php
  // in your header or along top of all php modules in your pap
  require_once ( '/path/to/includes/ini_set.php' );
  
  // ...
  
?>
```

and the ini_set.php script:

```
<?php
  // one of these for each override of defaults set in php.ini file --
  ini_set ( $varname, $newvalue );
  ini_set ( $varname, $newvalue );
  ini_set ( $varname, $newvalue );
?>
```

If you are interested in learning more about the ini_set() function, here is the documentation page on php.net: https://www.php.net/ini_set

Hope this was somewhat helpful ~

Comment: I was thinking about working on multiple apps simultaneously, and not using the same INI for all of them.  I also want to be able to easily move the apps to Linux or Windows without having to recreate the entire directory structure again because my includes have absolute paths in them.

Comment: Are there performance issues with setting PHP INI values on EVERY page load?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do so is to use PHP via FCGI (mod_fcgid). This way you can run PHP using a different user and a different php.ini per vHost.

Here's an example how to set up such a configuration on Ubuntu: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-8.10

Comment: I'll look into this if I can't find another method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use full path name, you can use that:

```
<?php
include  dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/include.php';
?>
```

---

[Possible solution for php.ini file](http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=3087)

Comment: Per the PHP documentation "If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned."  So that isn't that helpful either, in the case that an include includes other files.

Answer (score -1):

Try a relative path! Like:

```
<?php
include("./includes/include.php");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
include("includes/include.php");
?>
```

Comment: So the dot makes it go to the sub domains DocumentRoot?

Comment: the "." is always the current directory!

Comment: But that doesn't really help me... I need to include files based on the roto directory of the SUB DOMAIN.  If I have scripts five levels deep into the sub domain's root, then I can't use the current directory as the include starting point.  Right?